# Merging of OWL XML files without Protégé

Tags: java, xml, merge, jena, owl

How to merge 2 owl files into a single owl file without using protege file? It could be done using protege. But, my question is related to without using 'protege'

OWL/XML using Apache Jena in java

Comment: You didn't mention the format...RDF/XML, OWL/XML, N-Triples, etc... ?Clearly, for most of the formats, you need a tool that loads both into memory. Apache Jena, RDF4J are good tools that support many formats and do provided CLI. Or you write Java code and use the OWL API, or .... you see, information is missing to give better hints.

Comment: @aksw thanks a lot. I edited the question. Provided the missing information

Comment: Impossible as mentioned in the [documentation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/#formats)

Comment: Possible, if use some combined solution, e.g. [ONT-API](https://github.com/avicomp/ont-api/wiki/Formats). In that case owl-api storer will work with owl-api implementation based on jena. As to merging, one graph can be added to another triple by triple - it is one of the possible way. Also, some people may prefer just save as ttl from jena, read using owlapi-impl (from a standard owlapi supply), merge axioms one by one, save as owl/xml.